# Meaning of "straw beneath my feet" in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

I was reading 'Animal Farm' by George Orwell, in which, there was a sentence

> "but I know, as surely as I see this straw beneath my feet, that sooner or later justice will be done."

I dont understand what **"straw beneath my feet"** means here? Is it a phrase or idiom ?

Comment: It is not an idiom or an accepted phrase. It could just as easily have been a rat or paper beneath his feet. 

The phrase is just about the certainty of justice just as the straw is present in beneath his feet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speaker is Old Major, the highly-respected boar, around whom the animals of the farm have gathered to hear advice on taking over the farm from humans.  Orwell sets the scene thus:

> At one end of the big barn, on a sort of raised platform, Major was already
>   ensconced **on his bed of straw**, under a lantern which hung from a beam.

So when Major says "as surely as I see this straw beneath my feet", he's merely commenting on a fact that happens to be obvious.